# how to find out when std map memory overwritten by other code in the program?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, crash, overwrite

I have a static std map,  when running it is overwritten by other code in the program.
And crash not happen immediately. 
After a while , when access the map ,  I found the map value is not right.
How can I find out when and where is the std map overwritten by other code.
If it is a normal variable I can set a watch point to find when it is overwritten.
But it is a std::map , how can I find it out?

```
typedef std::map<std::string, MissileType *> MissileTypeMap;
static MissileTypeMap MissileTypes;
```

when initialize it contain 20 more value.
But when it is crash it shows  size=5
but no correct value in it.

I am using mac xcode clang to build it

Comment: What OS are you using if other programs can overwrite memory of another?

Comment: Are you using an optimized build?

Comment: sorry here I mean other code   In the same program.

Comment: Other programs can't overwrite your variables (except if you set some shared memory or use some unusual OS). It's likely you have some buffer overflow or alike somewhere.

Comment: no I did not do  optimized build.

Comment: So please edit title and text of your question... To find it use some debugger and set a watch point.

Comment: You should be able to set a watch point on the member variable of the `map` class that keeps the length. You might just have to do some digging to find where that is.

Comment: Let me make the topic simple ,  can I set a watch point for std::map to find when and where it is overwritten by other code in the program.

Comment: Yes , I know watch point could find it out, but how to set watch point to a std map I have tried. But failed.

Comment: std::map would occupy some region of memory (more probably discrete), so you wouldn't really know where to set up a watch, even if you can directly set watch on raw memory. So some really careful debug is required. If your program runs for a *long* time you can try to set some breakpoint on several position modifying the map (sampling), or you can simply set them on any point that modify the map. So long as you don't initialize a pointer manually with value, you rarely can overwrite some occupied memory.

Comment: I doubt the map structure is overwritten,  not the value it is point to.

Comment: Yes you could place a memory break point on the size of the map. If there is a size variable to be watched. If something "random" is going for a walk through your memory, you'd probably have better luck using something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to hunt it.

Comment: `std::map` always has a member to store the size. The C++ standard forbids `size()` to be implemented by walking the tree. A look at the [libcxx source](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include) shows this to be `MissileTypes.__tree_.__pair3_.__first_`. That should be suitable for a watchpoint.